# jQuery - After animation ends change background

Tags: jquery

I have an click event that is making my DIV move and change the background position

```
$("a.clickme").click(
function(){
$("#moveme").animate({left: -550 +"px"}, 2000);
$('#moveme').animate(2000).css({backgroundPosition: '0 -1px'});
});
```

It works like this to, but I need something that will make the background position change **after** the "move" (left: -550) is done.
Can you help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `callback`, [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate)

```
$("#moveme").animate({left: -550 +"px"}, 2000, function(){
    // codes here after the animation....
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great! :D in 12 minutes I will be able to accept your answer!